# Correcting for 3D Printing in blender removes key features of the model. I could use some advice on appropriate correction

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing

I'm trying to make a simple 3D model (My first 3D model). When using the add on Mesh: 3D print toolbox and clicking on make manifold, key features of my model are distorted in such a way that it's unusable. I understand that my model itself may be unsuitable. Also, I don't quite understand the intricacies of what this add on does or what "Make Manifold" does, but I would like some advice on it before I continue trying to make some things if possible.Below are some images of the model and the distortions that occur.

Before:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Possible issue with the face distortion. Unsure how to fix this though. Thought with clipping enabled it wouldn't have been an issue but like I said I'm very new to this.

[image: Highlighted edge possibly causing issues]

The tail was honestly kind of rough for me but it's the cleanest I've got it so far although I know it's not necessarily right, but the outer body is all one full piece.

[image: Inner Tail the tongue is part of it's backstrap]

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more about your project. Are you using a mirror modifier? If so, do you have merge and clipping enabled? Also, make sure your normals are all pointed the right way (select all in edit mode then Shift+N). Lastly - _manifold_ essentially means "continuous geometry", but for the sake of 3D printing, means "fully enclosed" (no gaps or holes, faces pointing in a continuous fashion, no "illegal" (non-planar) faces).

Comment: Okay thank you. Yes I am using a mirror modifier and I have clipping enabled. unfortunately some of the loop cuts on the feet are pretty messy so I could maybe see how that would mess up but the tail I cleaned up nicely(to the best of my current ability) as well as the head. I have deleted inner faces and such.  I did shift n as mentioned and it produced the same distorted results. If there is any other related information I could provide to better show the project I'm willing. I'm going to add a couple more images to the post of a possible reason for the issue.

Comment: Upon finding Mesh>Clean Up options and going through various steps I've manage to close off the hole on the inside of the tail and clean up a lot of the model. Also, since I came across select by trait, I noticed the non-manifold area is right at the symmetry line now. Is there some way of applying or finalizing this mirror modifier that maybe I've not done?

Comment: @PencilGraphite 3D print toolbox can be very confusing here's a good explanation of the options and how to fix them. https://youtu.be/0rgrLWFUjlk